# Setting antd form values from state or API

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

Currently using react + redux and I am trying to set the initial values of the form to what is in the state after it's been fetched from the API, but can't seem to figure it out. It works fine and I can update the profile without setting the initial values, but whenever i set the initial values i receive a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'gender' of null`..

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
const AboutMeForm = ({ profile: { profile }, updateProfile, getProfile }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  const initialState = {
    gender: null,
    maritalStatus: null,
    educationLevel: null,
    income: null,
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!profile) getProfile();
    if (profile) {
      const profileData = { ...initialState };
      for (const key in profile) {
        if (key in profileData) profileData[key] = profile[key];
      }
      setFormData(profileData);
      form.setFieldsValue({
        gender: formData.gender,
        maritalStatus: formData.maritalStatus,
        educationLevel: formData.educationLevel,
        income: formData.income,
      });
    }
  }, [getProfile, profile]);

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    updateProfile(values);
  };

  const onSubmitFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed: ', errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="mt-5">About Me</h2>

      <Alerts />
      <Form
        form={form}
        name="aboutMe"
        layout="vertical"
        initialValues={{
          gender: formData ? formData.gender : null,
        }}
        onFinish={onSubmit}
        onFinishFailed={onSubmitFailed}
      >
        <Row>
          <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={16}>
            <Row gutter={ROW_GUTTER}>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
                <Form.Item name="gender" label="Gender">
                  <Select placeholder="Select a Gender">
                    <Option value="MALE">Male</Option>
                    <Option value="FEMALE">Female</Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
                <Form.Item name="maritalStatus" label="Marital Status">
                  <Select placeholder="Select Marital Status">
                    <Option value="SINGLE">Single</Option>
                    <Option value="MARRIED">Married</Option>
                    <Option value="LIVING_TOGETHER">Living Together</Option>
                    <Option value="DIVORCED">No Longer Married</Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
                <Form.Item name="educationLevel" label="Education Level">
                  <Select placeholder="Select Education Level">
                    <Option value="SOME_HIGH_SCHOOL">
                      Some High School or Less
                    </Option>
                    <Option value="HIGH_SCHOOL">
                      High school graduate or equivalent (GED)
                    </Option>
                    <Option value="SOME_COLLEGE">
                      Some college, no degree
                    </Option>
                    <Option value="COLLEGE">College graduate</Option>
                    <Option value="SOME_GRADUATE_SCHOOL">
                      Graduate school, no degree
                    </Option>
                    <Option value="ASSOCIATE_DEGREE">Associate degree</Option>
                    <Option value="GRADUATE_SCHOOL">Masters degree</Option>
                    <Option value="PROFESSIONAL_DEGREE">
                      Professional Degree
                    </Option>
                    <Option value="DOCTORATE">Doctorate</Option>
                    <Option value="COLLEGE_DIPLOMA">College Diploma</Option>
                    <Option value="TRADE_SCHOOL">
                      Some college, no diploma
                    </Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
                <Form.Item name="income" label="Income">
                  <Select placeholder="Select Income">
                    <Option value="LESS_THAN_$25000">Less than $25,000</Option>
                    <Option value="$25000_$49999">$25,000 - $49,999</Option>
                    <Option value="$50000_$74999">$50,000 - $74,999</Option>
                    <Option value="$75000_$99999">$75,000 - $99,999</Option>
                    <Option value="$100000_$149999">$100,000 - $149,999</Option>
                    <Option value="$150000+">$150,000+</Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Save
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

AboutMeForm.propTypes = {
  updateProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateProfile, getProfile })(
  AboutMeForm
);
```

I've updated the code with what I currently have but still no luck pre-populating the fields..